# How to Convert Date in "01MAR1978:00:00:00" string format to Date Format in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have dates in the following formats:

1. 08MAR1978:00:00:00
2. 10FEB1973:00:00:00
3. 15AUG1982:00:00:00

I would like to convert them to:

1. 1978-03-08
2. 1973-02-10
3. 1982-09-15

I have tried the following in SparkR:

```
period_uts <- unix_timestamp(all.new$DATE_OF_BIRTH, '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
period_ts <- cast(period_uts, 'timestamp')
period_dt <- cast(period_ts, 'date')
df <- withColumn(all.new, 'p_dt', period_dt)
```

But when I do this, all the dates get changed into "NA".

Can anyone please provide some insights on how I can convert dates in %d%B%Y:%H:%M:%S format to dates in SparkR?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `as.Date(all.new$DATE_OF_BIRTH, format = "%d%B%Y:%H:%M:%S")` should convert it to your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
all.new = all.new %>% withColumn("Date_of_Birth_Fixed", to_date(.$DATE_OF_BIRTH,  "ddMMMyyyy"))
```

This works in Spark 2.2.x

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `SparkR` to solve this question.

What you have:

```
DoB <- c("08MAR1978:00:00:00", "10FEB1973:00:00:00", "15AUG1982:00:00:00")
```

If you want to get 1978-03-08 etc. you could just use `as.Date` in combination with the date format you already found yourself:

```
as.Date(DoB, format="%d%B%Y:%H:%M:%S")
# [1] "1978-03-08" "1973-02-10" "1982-08-15"
```

`as.Date` will ensure that `R` knows how to interpret your string as a date.

Note, however, that in general the way dates are displayed to you (i.e. 1978-03-08) actually don't really matter. The reason is that 'under the hood', `R` understands your date now, so all date-related operations will be performed appropriately.

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for your response. My data has +200 million rows, so I would have to do it in SparkR. I'll try implement the as.Date solution in SparkR, but I'm not sure if that is possible.